# How to use generic types with required fields in useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a custom React hook using useReducer. It is supposed to hold the state for array of objects and all objects must have an "id" field. Object structure other then id, should be generic.

Here's what I have;

```
export enum ArrayActions { INIT, ADD, UPDATE, DELETE }

type ArrayAction<T> =
  | { type: ArrayActions.INIT, payload: T[] }
  | { type: ArrayActions.ADD, payload: T }
  | { type: ArrayActions.UPDATE, payload: T }
  | { type: ArrayActions.DELETE, id: string }

type ObjWithId = { id:any, [key: string]: any }

function arrayReducer<T extends ObjWithId>(state: T[], action: ArrayAction<T>): T[] {
  switch(action.type){
    case ArrayActions.INIT:
      return [...action.payload]
    case ArrayActions.ADD: // TODO: check if id already exists
      return [...state, action.payload]
    case ArrayActions.UPDATE:
      return [...(state.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)), action.payload]
    case ArrayActions.DELETE:
      return state.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)
  }
}

export function useArrayReducer<T extends ObjWithId> (initialState: T[] = []): [T[], React.Dispatch<ArrayAction<T>>] {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(arrayReducer, initialState)
  return [state, dispatch]      // error!
}
```

`state` in the last line gives the following error;

```
Type 'ObjWithId[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
Type 'ObjWithId' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

I thought it might be related to definiton of `ObjWithId`, but couldn't exactly figure it out. Could you help me achieve the wanted result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs it;

```
export interface ListItem { 
  id: string | number | undefined;
  [key: string]: any;
}

export type Action<L extends ListItem> = 
  | { type: "init", items: L[]}
  | { type: "add", item: L }
  | { type: "update", item: L }
  | { type: "delete", id: NonNullable<L["id"]>}
```